# Bug with RadWindow?

Tags: wpf, windows-7, rad-controls, radwindow

I'm using RadWindow for WPF in my application.

I called RadWindow.ShowDialog() to show the RadWindow.

But when I minimize this RadWindow, it will disappear and then I can not restore it because it is not contained in Taskbar of Windows 7.

I solved this by hiding the Minimized button on RadWindow, but then I encountered other case of this bug. that when I press "Window + D" keys to minimize all Windows, this Radwindow also disappear.

Please help me to fix it,

Many thanks,

T&T Group

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you need to set the Owner property of your dialog window to the application's main window.

Answer (score 0):

RadWindow doesn't contain the property "ShowOnTaskBar" like Window have.
you can do something like this code below to work-around :

```
   Window _window;

        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Loaded += MainView_Loaded;

        }

        void MainView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _window = this.ParentOfType<Window>();

            if (_window != null)
            {
                _window.ShowInTaskbar = true;
                _window.Title = this.Header.ToString();
            }
        }
```